# TCP Data is received in the wrong order/lost

Tags: java, sockets, tcp

My TCP data is rarely, but enough for it to be noticeable, received in the wrong order, or lost entirely.

For example, my client would send `Log:joehot200;Password`, and the server would receive `ehot200;Password`

I checked [TCP - received in wrong order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20481674/tcp-received-in-wrong-order) and [TCP data occasionally received in wrong order and incomplete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12622435/tcp-data-occasionally-received-in-wrong-order-and-incomplete) and neither help. They both seem to have non-answers that do not give enough detail or do not solve the problem.

I am using this code to send data on the client and the server:

```
public void sendData(String data){ //Server code
    try{
        System.out.println("Sent " + data);
     DataOutputStream outToClient = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
     outToClient.writeBytes(data + "\n");
    }catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public void sendData(String data){ //Client code
    try{
    DataOutputStream outToServer = new DataOutputStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream());
      outToServer.writeBytes(data + "\n");
    }catch (Exception e){

    }
}
```

This is the sort of data that is being send/received:

```
Data: UID:1;Pitch:0.0
FROM SERVER: Name:1;joehot200
Data: Name:1;joehot200
FROM SERVER: Type:1;2
Data: Type:1;2
FROM SERVER: FlaBag:1;0
Data: FlaBag:1;0
FROM SERVER: Teall-104,442m:1;1
Data: Teall-104,442m:1;1
FROM SERVER: 6.572884235079,51.82797146606425,5670.44316581469,0
```

In fact, looking at that above data, even that is wrong!! I have no packet starting with FlaBag or Teall.

What's going wrong here?

I am sending data from multiple threads, though I am obviously receiving all the data on the same thread.

Comment: Are you by any chance using multiple threads? Could be a race condition.

Comment: This really shouldn't happen.  Your O/S should be taking care of out-of-order or missing packets for you.

Comment: @L33TS "Race condition"?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition#Software

Comment: @L33TS I'm confused though as to why that's relevant. It's not like I'm incrementing a number or something - I'm sending a packet.

Comment: Can you post a bit of more code? If each thread is using a different DataOutputStream, your package will arrive in order (in the same thread) but may be out of order on different threads, since those are separate TCP connections.

Comment: If you send the packets from multiple threads then they might not be send in the correct order. You either lock the send function or you pass a message to a single thread for sending. Locking the send is the most common.

Comment: @L33TS Locking the send would be stupid. I would want to pass them all to a single thread. But so would putting it into an array for sending, since requiring a CopyOnWriteArrayList for the amount of packets I sent/receive would also be stupid. What should I do?

Comment: @XapaJIaMnu All of the threads call that sendData() function, so I'm pretty sure it's the same DataOutputStream.

What "More" do you want? I want to avoid posting hundreds of my lines of code here.

Comment: It's not the same DataOutputStream since it's declared as a local variable in the function. All the threads are operating on their own DataOutputStream.

Comment: @L33TS Oh. Crap. That looks like it's the issue.

Should I declare the outputStream at the top of the class?

Comment: Yes, but you should still use locking to prevent it from being accessed by multiple threads at the same time. (Unless it's already thread-safe)

Comment: One thing  L33TS already said. i.e  DataOutputStream is local. another thing is , are you sure that you are receiving your data? Because you are not flushing/closing your stream.

Comment: @AJ. I'm successfully able to run around the map in my pirate ship, though my archers' arrows are jumpy due this issue.

Comment: @L33TS Could you please explain why I need to stop other threads from accessing it?

Comment: Read this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/6393126/2026276 (Despite that it's Python then it's essential to all languages)

Comment: This needs an mcve http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So basically the problem is that each of your functions that calls this function:

```
public void sendData(String data){ //Client code
try{
DataOutputStream outToServer = new DataOutputStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream());
  outToServer.writeBytes(data + "\n");
}catch (Exception e){

}
}
```

Calls it in a separate context, so it will create thread local DataOutputStream which will be destroyed once the thread leaves the sendData context, effectively multiple clients are sending multiple tcp packets which arrive in order, but the clients are not synchronised. To get around this issue what you should do is to declare **DataOutputStream** outside of your function and make the method [synchronized](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/syncmeth.html). This will prevent multiple threads from executing the same method at the same time. In the end your code should look something like that:

```
public class Blaaa {
    ...
    DataOutputStream outToServer = new DataOutputStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream());
    public synchronized void sendData(String data) {
        outToServer.writeBytes(data + "\n");
    }
 }
```

This should take care of out of order receiving, but your threads can still invoke the sedData method out of order (though at least it will not interleave). You might need some additional logic to prevent that.

Comment: I've accepted this answer because it appears to solve my issue. Many thanks to you all - Your help is greatly appreciated!